# Not able to fetch upto 2 values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => zero
    [1] => first
    [2] => second
    [3] => third
)
```

I am trying to fetch the first 2 values for that I have the following code

```
<?php if($skillArray['0']): ?>
<p><?php echo ucwords($skillArray['0']); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($skillArray['1']): ?>
<p><?php echo ucwords($skillArray['1']); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If there are 2 values in array then it works fine but if there is only 1 value in array then the 2nd if condition throws an error

Can anyone please tell how to get the first 2 values from this type of array and if there is only 1 value then it should not throw any error and display only the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_slice does not return any error if array has not items enough and returns no more than 2 items with such arguments

```
foreach(array_slice($skillArray, 0,2) as $x) {
    echo "<p>".ucwords($x)."</p>";
};
```

Answer (score 2):

use `sizeof($array)` and check the no of elements present in the array.
If the size is equal to 1 then terminate the condition

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `for loop` like below

```
for($i=0;$i<count($skillArray);$i++){
    echo "<p>".ucwords($skillArray[$i])."</p>";
}
```

Using for loop you don't need to use condition and your code reduce to less number of lines

Answer (score 0):

Use the count function to determine the length.

if (count($skillArray) > 1) ...

Answer (score 0):

**There are several ways to do that**,

1. Need to Check the second value by using **isset()** method of PHP
2. In simple way you can **iterate over values** of array by to **get the total count values** of that array using count($yourArray)
3. **use sizeof($array)** and check the no of elements present in the array. And then simple make use of foreach loop over elements.